# List created by jQuery takes a lot of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSON array which has 9000 records and it is displayed using list li. The HTML object is created using jQuery :

```
$j.each(DTOList, function(index,obj) {
              var $li = $j("<li/>");
              var $button = $j("<button/>", { type: "button" , onClick:"location.href='playfile.html?messageId="+obj.id+"&operation=play&to="+obj.to+"&from="+obj.from+"'" });
              var $parentDiv = $j("<div/>", { class: "buttonMargin" });
              var $numDiv =  $j("<div/>", { class: "num" ,text:obj.to});
              var $nameDiv =  $j("<div/>", { class: "name" ,text:obj.from});
              var $timeDiv =  $j("<div/>", { class: "time" , text:obj.time});

              $parentDiv.append($numDiv);
              $parentDiv.append($nameDiv);
              $parentDiv.append($timeDiv);
              $parentDiv.append($j("<hr>"));

              $j("#datalist").append($li.append($button.append($parentDiv)));

        });
```

Here is an example of li created by the above code:

```
<li>
    <button type="button"
        onclick="location.href='playfile.html?messageId=1165484222&amp;operation=play&amp;to=Fax Line&amp;from=abc'">
        <div class="buttonMargin">
            <div class="num">Fax Line</div>
            <div class="name">def</div>
            <div class="time">Jan 04,2018 12:02:44 AM</div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </button>
<li>
```

The problem here is, the above code takes at least 1.5 mins to load and till then my HTML page is blank. Is there any way to improve the above code to increase performance?

Comment: Use pagination and/or delayed DOM manipulation (eg. in setInterval). The page should be allowed to *perform the first refresh* very soon.

Comment: Lazy loading technique should be used I guess. Initially add 1000 list items and then user scrolls again 1000 and so on this could reduce the load on the page.

Comment: is it possible to generate HTML itself in worker and just append it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/9) performance test. Use `for` loop instead of `.each()` function. 
[image][image]

Comment: Interesting, but still **largely irrelevant**. The OP is looping *a mere 9000 times*.

Comment: Also, that *microbenchmark* has a really poor `fn` definition - `x = x`? The JS engine might even *entirely eliminate that code* - so the time is *dominated* by the loop and not any *actual* work that would be done. In the case of this question. the loading is slow **not because of the looping construct**, but because of the relatively expensive DOM manipulation (done inline with the page load) done while looping.

Comment: See https://tomdale.net/2017/07/adventures-in-microbenchmarking/ , http://daniel.mitterdorfer.name/articles/2014/benchmarking-flaws/ , http://haifux.org/lectures/311/BM_crimes.pdf etc. (Basically, any result from a search for "dangers of microbenchmarks")

Comment: Yes it seems, but it can be a slight performance increase by changing the loop @user2864740

Comment: At 9k ops/second (as from that screenshot), `$.each` is still iterating an effective *4.5 million items per second* (9k/s * 500), while the OP needs to iterate only 9000 items. Put another way, even with the `$.each` (at 9k ops/second) it would only take 1/500s (or *0.2 milliseconds*!) to iterate all 9k (9000) items. This is not the worm you are looking for :}

Comment: The OPs current code takes 1.5 minutes (or 90k = 90000 milliseconds) so even if eliminating a ridiculous optimistic 1000 milliseconds by changing the loop structure - and I'm being *super generous* (as even fixing the simple herpderp math error it's only *2 milliseconds*), see above - would make *no effective difference*.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL I dont think it will help me much , but still i changed it to for and the difference is very small. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

Likely the main problem here is the DOM operation performed in this line

```
$j("#datalist").append($li.append($button.append($parentDiv)));
```

triggering document reflows over and over....

So as a first improvement try to generate all items first (without appending it into the DOM) and then append them afterwards with one single operation.

Something like this:

```
var elements = [];

$j.each(DTOList, function(index,obj) {
         .....
         elements.push($li);
});

$j("#datalist").append(elements);
```

Comment: Currently I am using jquery-1.11.3, i will make the code changes and let you know.thanks

Comment: For edit: If there are questions for the OP, they should be in the Comments section of the question itself (sometimes it makes sense in the Comments section of the answer, but questions should not be *in* answers unless they are rhetorical/answered..)